# Writing a notification descriptor value in iOS using bluetooth

Tags: xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Plugin.BLE to iterate a bluetooth device's services / characteristics / descriptors.  When I find the descriptor I'm looking for, I try enabling notifications by writing 02-00 into the descriptor.  This works for Android devices but on iOS, I get a an error:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason:  Client Characteristic Configuration descriptors must be configured using setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic
```

The offending C# code looks like:

```
await descriptor.WriteAsync(new byte[2] { 02, 00 });
```

Is there a different way on iOS devices to enable notifications?

Comment: Hi , do you mean this code (`await descriptor.WriteAsync(new byte[2] { 02, 00 });`) not working in IOS ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes.  iOS throws an error which I believe is related to the fact that writing 02-00 into a descriptor turns on notifications.  I belive iOS has a specific method SetNotifyValue but that method is not exposed to me.

Comment: Okey , if each time occurs in IOS , it needs to have a try with using [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth?language=objc) native method to check it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparent that this is one of those platform specific issues that will have to be refactored out into an interface / platform-implementation pattern.  So for the iOS version of the application, in order to do the above, I had to write against CoreBluetooth.  Once you have your device / service / characteristic / client configuration descriptor, you call the following:

```
peripheral.SetNotifyValue(true, characteristic);
```

After setting that value, a callback is issued to the peripheral delegate:

```
public override void UpdatedCharacterteristicValue(CBPeripheral peripheral, CBCharacteristic characteristic, NSError error) { }
```

From there I was able to continue what I was doing before.